# Android CoverFlow is not work perfactly in SONY S tablet with same code

Tags: android, coverflow

I am trying to implement the CoverFlow. Using the same code in other devices looks perfect but in SONY S Tablet its not looking propering. I attached below screenshot of SONY S. I have used Android 4.0 in my demo.

I am not able to understand the problem. Is is device oriented or is any problem in my code?

If anyone can understand then please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

My code below

```
public class CoverFlowExample extends Activity 
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        CoverFlow coverFlow;
        coverFlow = new CoverFlow(this);

        coverFlow.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        ImageAdapter coverImageAdapter =  new ImageAdapter(this);

        coverImageAdapter.createReflectedImages();

        coverFlow.setAdapter(coverImageAdapter);

        coverFlow.setSpacing(-50);
        coverFlow.setSelection(8, true);

        setContentView(coverFlow);

        //Use this if you want to use XML layout file
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //coverFlow =  (CoverFlow) findViewById(R.id.coverflow);
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        int mGalleryItemBackground;
        private Context mContext;

//      private FileInputStream fis;

        private Integer[] mImageIds =
        {
                R.drawable.kasabian_kasabian,
                R.drawable.starssailor_silence_is_easy,
                R.drawable.killers_day_and_age,
                R.drawable.garbage_bleed_like_me,
                R.drawable.death_cub_for_cutie_the_photo_album,
                R.drawable.kasabian_kasabian,
                R.drawable.massive_attack_collected,
                R.drawable.muse_the_resistance,
                R.drawable.starssailor_silence_is_easy
        };

        private ImageView[] mImages;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) 
        {
            mContext = c;
            mImages = new ImageView[mImageIds.length];
        }
        public boolean createReflectedImages() 
        {
                //The gap we want between the reflection and the original image
                final int reflectionGap = 4;


                int index = 0;
                for (int imageId : mImageIds)
                {
                    Bitmap originalImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
                            imageId);
                    int width = originalImage.getWidth();
                    int height = originalImage.getHeight();


                    //This will not scale but will flip on the Y axis
                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    matrix.preScale(1, -1);

                    //Create a Bitmap with the flip matrix applied to it.
                    //We only want the bottom half of the image
                    Bitmap reflectionImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalImage, 0, height/2, width, height/2, matrix, false);


                    //Create a new bitmap with same width but taller to fit reflection
                    Bitmap bitmapWithReflection = Bitmap.createBitmap(width 
                      , (height + height/2), Config.ARGB_8888);

                   //Create a new Canvas with the bitmap that's big enough for
                   //the image plus gap plus reflection
                   Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapWithReflection);
                   //Draw in the original image
                   canvas.drawBitmap(originalImage, 0, 0, null);
                   //Draw in the gap
                   Paint deafaultPaint = new Paint();
                   canvas.drawRect(0, height, width, height + reflectionGap, deafaultPaint);
                   //Draw in the reflection
                   canvas.drawBitmap(reflectionImage,0, height + reflectionGap, null);

                   //Create a shader that is a linear gradient that covers the reflection
                   Paint paint = new Paint(); 
                   LinearGradient shader = new LinearGradient(0, originalImage.getHeight(), 0, 
                     bitmapWithReflection.getHeight() + reflectionGap, 0x70ffffff, 0x00ffffff, 
                     TileMode.CLAMP); 
                   //Set the paint to use this shader (linear gradient)
                   paint.setShader(shader); 
                   //Set the Transfer mode to be porter duff and destination in
                   paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_IN)); 
                   //Draw a rectangle using the paint with our linear gradient
                   canvas.drawRect(0, height, width, 
                     bitmapWithReflection.getHeight() + reflectionGap, paint); 

                   ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                   imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapWithReflection);
                   imageView.setLayoutParams(new CoverFlow.LayoutParams(120, 180));
                   imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
                   mImages[index++] = imageView;

                }
                return true;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mImageIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            //Use this code if you want to load from resources
            //ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);
            //i.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
            //i.setLayoutParams(new CoverFlow.LayoutParams(130, 130));
            //i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);           
            //return i;

            return mImages[position];
        }
         /** Returns the size (0.0f to 1.0f) of the views 
         * depending on the 'offset' to the center. */ 
         public float getScale(boolean focused, int offset) { 
           /* Formula: 1 / (2 ^ offset) */ 
             return Math.max(0, 1.0f / (float)Math.pow(2, Math.abs(offset))); 
         } 

    }

}
```

**Output in SONY S**

[image]

Comment: Why are you using hard coded pixel values throughout your code?  I suspect that this will fail on many different devices.  You should be using dpi.

Comment: I am not getting your point can u please explain me or give me example?

Comment: Here for example `imageView.setLayoutParams(new CoverFlow.LayoutParams(120, 180));`

Comment: But I dont need to define LayoutParams I want to display this into full screen. And more thing in other devices everything is disply perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

you need to call child.invalidate() in offsetChildrenLeftAndRight() method. Or where you are setting your imageview to center child call this method.